Podman - Port Still Listening Even After I Stop Container
I started a simple container in podman using
podman run -d -p 8080:8080 --name myapp registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/httpd-24

Once run, I stop the container by
podman stop myapp

but the port 8080 is still listening even after the container is stopped. podman ps shows no container is running and lsof -i :8080 shows a process running in port 8080.
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
exe     27998 ubntuusr   12u  IPv6 530707      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)

I have to kill the process to release the port every time.
Please guide me if I'm doing anything wrong here.
Regards,
Yasothar

What does netstat show for that port?

```tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)

Hmm bizarre. I could understand TIME_WAIT, but not LISTEN after the process has exited.

Apologies if this information is late but I'm running Ubuntu on a Windows 11 as a subsystem.

That is IPv6 so if you weren't trying to use that it is probably just some bit of infrastructure. If you could identify exactly what the process was that would pin it down.

Hi Richard, I followed your advice, checked the /proc/ with a cat cmdline and got the following output. containers-rootlessport, searched in google and found the following similar question in a different forum. "https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/17852/what-is-this-rootlessport-and-how-to-get-it-to-release-the-port-hold", couldn't come to any conclusion but thank for the guidance.
